# How to do next frame predictions using Pytorch CNN-LSTM?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm doing next frame prediction from static images extracted from video and save into disk. I'm using CNN-LSTM, during training feed the model 5 frames and predict the 6th frame, but during evaluation I want the CNN-LSTM model to take it's prediction and use it as input to predict the next future frame it should repeat until predict the 6th frame.

**How do you pass the predicted frame from then CNN-LSTM as an input in the next step for 6 iterations?** Here is the sample code for my CNN-LSTM model:

```
class CRNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channels=3, sample_size=64, num_classes=100,
            hidden_size=512, num_layers=1, rnn_unit='LSTM'):
    super(CRNN, self).__init__()
    self.in_channels=in_channels
    self.sample_size = sample_size
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    self.rnn_unit=rnn_unit

    # network params
    self.ch1, self.ch2= 64, 128
    self.k1, self.k2 = (5, 5), (5, 5)
    self.s1, self.s2 = (1, 1), (1, 1)
    self.p1, self.p2 = (0, 0), (0, 0)
    self.d1, self.d2 = (1, 1), (1, 1)
    self.input_size  = self.ch2
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers  = num_layers

    # network architecture
    # in_channels=3 for rgb
    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.in_channels, out_channels=self.ch1, kernel_size=self.k1, stride=self.s1, padding=self.p1, dilation=self.d1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(self.ch1, momentum=0.01),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.ch1, out_channels=self.ch1, kernel_size=1, stride=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    )
    self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.ch1, out_channels=self.ch2, kernel_size=self.k2, stride=self.s2, padding=self.p2, dilation=self.d2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(self.ch2, momentum=0.01),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.ch2, out_channels=self.ch2, kernel_size=1, stride=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    )

    if self.rnn_unit=='LSTM':
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
        input_size=self.input_size,
        hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
        dropout= 0.5 if self.num_layers > 1 else 0,
        num_layers=self.num_layers,
        batch_first=True,
    )
    if self.rnn_unit=='GRU':
        self.lstm = nn.GRU(
        input_size=self.input_size,
        hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
        dropout= 0.5 if self.num_layers > 1 else 0,
        num_layers=self.num_layers,
        batch_first=True,
    )
    if self.rnn_unit=='RNN':
        self.lstm = nn.RNN(
        input_size=self.input_size,
        hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
        dropout= 0.5 if self.num_layers > 1 else 0,
        num_layers=self.num_layers,
        batch_first=True,
    )

  
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.num_classes)
    self.act = nn.Sigmoid()

def forward(self, X, n_steps=None):
    # CNN
    # x: (batch_size, channel, t, h, w)
    cnn_embed_seq = []
    if n_steps is None: # Code for training
        for t in range(X.size(2)):
            # Conv
            x = self.conv1(X[:, :, t, :, :])
            x = self.conv2(x)

            x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
            cnn_embed_seq.append(x)

        cnn_embed_seq = torch.stack(cnn_embed_seq, dim=0)
        
        # batch first
        cnn_embed_seq = cnn_embed_seq.transpose_(0, 1)

        # LSTM
        hidden=None
        # use faster code paths
        self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
        out, hidden = self.lstm(cnn_embed_seq, hidden)
        # MLP
        # out: (batch, seq, feature), choose the last time step
        out = self.fc1(out[:, -1, :])
        out = self.act(out)

    if n_steps is not None: # Code for prediction
        for t in range(n_steps): 
            # Conv
            x = self.conv1(X[:, :, 0, :, :])
            x = self.conv2(x)
  
            x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
            # cnn_embed_seq.append(x)

            # cnn_embed_seq = torch.stack(cnn_embed_seq, dim=0)
            # batch first
            # x = x.transpose_(0, 1)
            # print('pred:',x.shape, t)

            x = x[ :, np.newaxis, :]
            # LSTM
            hidden=None
            # use faster code paths
            self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
            # print('LSTM out', out.shape)
            # MLP
            # out: (batch, seq, feature), choose the last time step
            out = self.fc1(out[:, -1, :])
            # X[:, 1, :, :, :] = out.view(-1, 1, self.sample_size,self.sample_size)
            out = self.act(out)
            X[:, 1, :, :, :] = out.view(-1, 1, self.sample_size,self.sample_size)

    return out
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I have added the question. how do you do next frame prediction using CNN-LSTM in Pytorch?

Comment: You begin the question saying that you are "doing next frame prediction". I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the question in bold